# Let $\sum_{r = 1}^{n}r^{4}=f(n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $$\sum_{r = 1}^{n}r^{4}=f(n)$$

then $$\sum_{r = 1}^{n}(2r-1)^{4}=$$

$A. f(2n)-16f(n)$ for all natural numbers $n$
$B. f(n)-16f((n-1)/2)$, when $n$ is odd
$C. f(n)-16f(n/2)$, when $n$ is even
$D.$ None of the above

Tried expanding the brackets but got stuck..

Comment: why the downvotes ??

Comment: other users do not invite questions with zero effort... so, I have asked you what have you tried... you have replied with nothing.. so it is put on hold.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have by change of index

$$f(2n)=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}k^4=\sum_{r=1}^n(2r-1)^4+\underbrace{\sum_{r=1}^n(2r)^4}_{=16f(n)}$$
so what option you choose?

Comment: That would be option A.. thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.